# Implementing a decision tree database in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a decision tree, and will probably (unless given an alternate) need a database of Nodes, with quickly accessible meta data. I'm going to have thousands to tens of thousands of Nodes, all with a little bit of instance data, some that are objects.

Should I use a mySQL database, or is there a better way of implementing databases in Java?

Also, I'm thinking that I'll need a database because it would be better to have all of the nodes pre-instantiated rather than instantiating all of them when the program starts. This logic makes sense right?

Comment: MySQL would not be such a good choice because "tree" mostly implies recursive queries and MySQL lacks many [modern SQL features](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) - including the ability to do recursive queries.

Comment: Don't optimize before you need to. Measure the impact of building tens of thousands of nodes when the program starts.  You may find it's not worth the effort to use a database.

Comment: Ok. Well, I will need a static list of Nodes because the multiple users will be accessing the same list, and changing it slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSql databases will not work well in this case, because you will have to do joints.

MySql database can do joints however it you have to specify specific number of joints(how many decisions will be made) will be done.

Your best option is to use graph database, because decision tree will have numerous links (relations yes/no). Example of such database:
http://neo4j.com/

Answer (score 1):

as long as you don't have memory problem, then i suggest `mongoDB`. alternatively few 100k of nodes is nothing in java. so if you don't have to reload things, just have it as part of ur java implementation. mysql is good. but connecting to it might be time consuming

Answer (score 1):

If you find you need a database (see my comment on your question) it sounds like an embedded database would be more suitable than the databases suggested in other answers.  I've had success with [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) - you can start and stop it in your application.

Still, I first recommend determining if you really need a database before adding one to your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with trees, consider a dbms that support hierarchical queries, for example Oracle or Postgres

Answer (score 0):

I always go for mySql. Since it is easy to use. And help is readily available for it. If you consider a proper standard, the I think Oracle will do.